# Creating a time-series from an image-collection in GEE including null-values in case all pixels are masked

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a time-series from an image-collection resulting in a list with the time-series values. It could be however, that some of the images in the collection are completely masked (i.e. have no valid pixels) in my Area-of-Interest. I create the time-series in GEE using this script (the first line is just to make a dummy image-collection, which has one fully masked image) (https://code.earthengine.google.com/9aa3e051390d72fac3fa783b009b08b4):

```
var img_col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ee.Image(5), 
                                             ee.Image(7).updateMask(ee.Image(0)), 
                                             ee.Image(10)]);

var create_ts = function(img){

  var value = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: aoi, scale: 10000});

  var ft = ee.Feature(null, value);

  return ft;
};

var ts = img_col.map(create_ts);

print(ts);
print(ts.aggregate_array('constant'));
```

The image-collection contains three images, the printed ts shows only two values however:

```
[5, 10]
```

but I would preferably like to have something like this:

```
[5, null, 10]
```

as output. If it's not possible to have "null" values in a list/array, then some kind of No-Data-Value would be acceptable as well, like for example:

```
[5, -9999, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this question [Property with null-value disappearing from feature when creating a feature-collection in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300986/property-with-null-value-disappearing-from-feature-when-creating-a-feature-colle/301170#301170) it follows that the "[5, null, 10]"-option is not feasible.

Adjusting the code like this solves the problem (with an option to pass multiple reducers to the reduceRegion-method, because its unnecessary to explicitly write the key-names) (https://code.earthengine.google.com/f7512d21e29ee477f3a8664a98675793):

```
var img_col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ee.Image(5), 
                                             ee.Image(7).updateMask(ee.Image(0)), 
                                             ee.Image(10)]);

var create_ts = function(img){

  var value = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: aoi, scale: 10000});

  value = value.map(function(key, val){return ee.List([val, -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())});

  var ft = ee.Feature(null, value);

  return ft;
};

var ts = img_col.map(create_ts);

print(ts);
print(ts.aggregate_array('constant'));
```

Comment: It is possible to have `[5,null,10]` if you use something like this: `ts.aggregate_array('constant').map(function(aitem) {
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(aitem).neq(ee.Number(-9999)),aitem, null );
})`. (note that `.replaceAll(-9999, null)` would be the obv solution but doesn't work). Pointing this out because I needed the -9999s to be null for my particular case