# Remove all properties from Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How does one go about removing properties from an Image object in Google Earth Engine?

I thought maybe I could remove properties one at a time by setting them to null (which apparently you can do for Features, based on [Property with null-value disappearing from feature when creating feature-collection in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300986)

How do you remove multiple properties from an image?

Example:

```
var im = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LT4_L1T_TOA/LT40280331982317XXX01");

var imcc = im.get('CLOUD_COVER');
print(imcc); 

var im2 = im.set('CLOUD_COVER', null);
var im2cc = im2.get('CLOUD_COVER');
print(im2cc);
print(im2);
```

Which sets the property `CLOUD_COVER` to `null`, but doesn't actually remove the property itself: 
[image]

I'm only trying to do this as an exercise to learn the structures of objects in Google Earth Engine and how to manipulate them.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question. When a question is about code a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck should be presented as formatted text within its body.

Comment: why do you want to remove the properties? you got to be more specific in telling which is your goal, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: Don't remove properties. Just use .select(['LIST_OF_PROPERTIES]) on features or feature Collections to show only the ones you need for further calculations/ export.